# Cannot read specific NDEF record with iPhone (iOS)

Tags: android, ios, nfc, ndef

I write a custom content consisting of 3 NDEF records (URL, Custom, Custom) onto a NFC tag. Such a tag is readable by both Android and iOS, no problems.

Now I increase the size of the URL, so naturally only URL NDEF record changes and the NDEF is no longer readable by iOS - receiving empty NDEF record list.

This looks very weird - if I pad the URL to a couple of characters it becomes readable (yet this is not a solution to me as the NDEF content is limited).

Tried with different iPhones (iOS 15, iOS 16). Tag of ISO 15693.

Manually validated NDEF record - all fields look good and consistent. There is an online NDEF checker it also gives no problems.

I am totally lost. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to dump the hex data from the ISO 15693 Tag, so it can be checked against the specs, you also need to show the code you used to write the NDEF message. without both of these it is difficult to help. You should also read the NFC Foroum specs for this type of Tag.

Comment: Yes that's why I wrote "validated NDEF record" so the problem was NOT in NDEF record.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well it required A LOT OF EFFORTS. Hope the related Apple engineer (engineers) will find this question and ask questions to themsselves.

So problem was generally with ISO 15693 tags. Those include additionally so called Capability Container - a 4 byte field at the user address 0x0. This header includes "size of content" expressed in 8-byte chunks. So real size divided by 8. In my case it was 0x12 which meant 0x24 blocks - AND - my content was exactly this size. So technically no specification violation is observed. Yet tags were not readable (specifically, NDEF message not recognized).

I have increased the content size to 1 unit (+8 bytes) and everything started to work.

Comment: The capability container does not specify "size of content", if specifies "The  maximum 
length of the NDEF file in bytes minus 2" (Taken from NFC Type 5 Specs), The capability Container is usually static (read only). The first 2 bytes of the NDEF file which begins in the next block specifies the exact size of the actual NDEF message.

Comment: Where this "minus 2" comes from? I have an ISO document open and it states: "MLEN SHALL be the size of the T5T_Area in bytes divided by 8."  no sign of any 2 offset etc.

Comment: So the wording comes direct from the specification from the NFC Forum of how to store Ndef on a Type 5 (V) Tag. I presume that as the NDEF file takes 2 bytes at the start of the NDEF file to store the length of the NDEF message, then the max NDEF message is the max NDEF file size minus these 2 bytes (The NDEF file is given in multiples of 8 byte blocks). The ISO document probably defines the data area available, where as the NFC Forum Spec defines how to store a NDEF message in that area.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I was reading exactly NFC Forum spec. Do I get it properly that 2 bytes offset is your assumption?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at as the question is vague without any technical details, just your statement about the capabilty container is wrong, as the capability container is about the maximum capabilties of the Tag, not actually what you are using for your content. The actual content just needs to be smaller than then Tags capabilities.

Comment: Mainly I want to see a reference for "The actual content just needs to be smaller" and I haven't seen one yet. I expect that to be defined strictly somewhere. Otherwise it is all amateurish.